# Responsive background images (serving best size for performance)

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

In the following CSS code, will both images be fetched?

```
.class {
    background-image: url(https://img.com/small);

    @screen (min-width: 700px) {
       background-image: url(https://img.com/big);
    }
}
```

We don't want to serve big images to mobile devices. We have `srcset/sizes`, but that's not for background images. We have `image-set()`, but that seems to care about pixel density, not screen width (I think). How do you handle this problem?

Comment: Wrap the first declaration in `@screen (max-width: 699px) {...}`

Comment: Did you check the network tab to see whether both are fetched or not?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I didn't think to check network tab as @TJ suggested. Turns out (in Chrome at least) they don't all get fetched, and when you resize the screen the new images get fetched.

I think I will use this postcss mixin, but I would still be interested if anyone has other methods.

```
@define-mixin responsive-bg-img $src {
  background-image: url('$(src)?nf_resize=fit&w=smallpx');

  @screen sm {
    background-image: url('$(src)?nf_resize=fit&w=mediumpx');
  }

  @screen md {
    background-image: url('$(src)?nf_resize=fit&w=largepx');
  }
}

.responsive-bg-img-wine {
  @mixin responsive-bg-img ../assets/lfs/wine.png;
}
```